# Number of weeks between two dates using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return the number of weeks between two dates using JavaScript.

So I have the following variables:

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear();

if(day < 10) { day= '0' + day; }
if(month < 10) { month = '0' + month; }

var dateToday = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;

var dateEndPlacement = '22/06/2014';
```

I've also prefixed the days and months with 0 if they are less than 10. Not sure if this is the correct way to do this... so alternative ideas would be welcomed.

And then I pass these two dates to the following function:

```
function calculateWeeksBetween(date1, date2) {
    // The number of milliseconds in one week
    var ONE_WEEK = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
    // Convert both dates to milliseconds
    var date1_ms = date1.getTime();
    var date2_ms = date2.getTime();
    // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
    var difference_ms = Math.abs(date1_ms - date2_ms);
    // Convert back to weeks and return hole weeks
    return Math.floor(difference_ms / ONE_WEEK);
}
```

However I get the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object 04/04/2014 has no method 'getTime'`

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

For those that are asking/gonna ask, I'm calling the function like this:

```
 calculateWeeksBetween(dateToday, dateEndPlacement);
```

Comment: are your date1 & date2 - date objects

Comment: Following advice to add the leading "0" to day and month. Use this code: `("0"+day).slice(-2)`

Comment: datePlacement is not an date object ...its an string object...use like var datePlacement = new Date(22,6,2014);

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp JS date objects

Answer (score 27):

I would recommend using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for this kind of thing.

But if you want to do it in pure javascript here is how I would do it:

```
function weeksBetween(d1, d2) {
    return Math.round((d2 - d1) / (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
}
```

Then call with

```
weeksBetween(new Date(), new Date(2014, 6, 22));
```

Comment: I know this is really old, but could you explain this operation: `(7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`?

Comment: That is how you calculate the length of a week. 7 days * 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 5):

You are storing your dates as strings (`'22/06/2014'`). `getTime` is a method of `Date`. You need to create `Date` objects for the dates, and pass those into the function.

```
var dateToday = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
var dateEndPlacement = new Date(2014, 5, 22);

calculateWeeksBetween(dateToday, dateEndPlacement);
```

As @Mosho notes, you can also subtract the dates directly, without using `getTime`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it'd be something silly I'd done wrong like this.

Answer (score 4):

If you need actual weeks between to dates, and not the number of seven days between them:

```
const week = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const day = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

function startOfWeek(dt) {
    const weekday = dt.getDay();
    return new Date(dt.getTime() - Math.abs(0 - weekday) * day);
}

function weeksBetween(d1, d2) {
    return Math.ceil((startOfWeek(d2) - startOfWeek(d1)) / week);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use moment itself have all the functionality I mentioned the below code which could work perfectly

```
var a = moment(a, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
var b = moment(b, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
days=b.diff(a, 'week');
```

don't forget to use moment js CDN

Answer (score 1):

subtract dates (which, unformatted, are the number of seconds elapsed since  1 January 1970 00:00:00) , divide by 604,800,000 (milliseconds per week).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1):

You should convert **dateToday** and **dateEndPlacement** to **Date** type.
Please read [Converting string to date in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js)