# How can I write this function without a bunch of if else statements?

Tags: javascript

I basically just can't figure this one out and don't want to hack it.

It will look so messy if I do this for 52 weeks in a year.

Any tips?

**Update**

This question is not about getting the year's current week.

This question is about getting weeks elapsed since a date defined.

I want the next week's workout to show up on 6th day of the current week ;)

**Example**

My days since start are 99: 2018-05-30 18:39:29.

Some of your examples are showing me on week 15.

My code however shows week 16, which is right. See the caveat?

```
  calculateUsersCurrentWorkoutWeek: function(timestamp) {
            let daysSinceSignup = moment().diff(timestamp, "days");
            if (daysSinceSignup <= 6) {
              return 1;
            } else if (daysSinceSignup > 6 && daysSinceSignup <= 13) {
              return 2;
            } else if (daysSinceSignup > 13 && daysSinceSignup <= 20) {
              return 3;
            } else if (daysSinceSignup > 20 && daysSinceSignup <= 27) {
              return 4;
            } else if (daysSinceSignup > 27 && daysSinceSignup <= 34) {
              return 5;
            } else if (daysSinceSignup > 34 && daysSinceSignup <= 41) {
              return 6;
            } else if (daysSinceSignup > 41 && daysSinceSignup <= 48) {
              return 7;
            } else if (daysSinceSignup > 48 && daysSinceSignup <= 55) {
              return 8;
            } else if (daysSinceSignup > 55 && daysSinceSignup <= 62) {
              return 9;
            } else if (daysSinceSignup > 55 && daysSinceSignup <= 62) {
              return 10;
            } else if (daysSinceSignup > 62 && daysSinceSignup <= 69) {
              return 11;
            } else if (daysSinceSignup > 69 && daysSinceSignup <= 76) {
              return 12;
            } else if (daysSinceSignup > 76 && daysSinceSignup <= 83) {
              return 13;
            } else if (daysSinceSignup > 83 && daysSinceSignup <= 90) {
              return 14;
            } else if (daysSinceSignup > 90 && daysSinceSignup <= 97) {
              return 15;
            } else {
              return 16;
            }
          }
```

Comment: divide by 7 and floor?

Comment: Will that give me accurate results as shown in the if else, which precisely controls things. Actually this is for displaying week workouts and I want the next weeks workouts to show up before the 7th day of the week, so a day in advance.

Comment: @Michel This is wrong. I want to show next week on the 6th day.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859704/number-of-weeks-between-two-dates-using-javascript

Comment: @Rajesh Technically you are right. But looking at OPs question het wants a `workoutweek`, so I suspect the actual day doesn't matter. You just have to follow a week scheme of tedious workouts in the gym, so you can go to the pub afterwards without a guilty conscience ;-)

Comment: @Michel Yup. OP updated it later. So have added a link for a dupe.

Comment: Nice work, but if I run my old code, I am on Week 16. Your code shows Week 15. ;) My days since start are 99, so it should show 16th week, not 15th. My start date is 2018-05-30 18:39:29.

Comment: @Ali Gajini. No it isn't. You have an error in your code at week 9 and 10: twice the same `else if(...)` for different week numbers.

Comment: Oh my bad. You are right.

Comment: What if I want this code to start from 1 again after every 16 weeks have elapsed? So batch of 16 weeks and then start again. On and on..

Comment: @Ali Gajani. I suggest you think about that for a moment or two, write some code and if you're stuck, ask a new question.

Comment: @Michel I noticed a problem in the answer. If the startDate=today, it gives me 0th week?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Divide by 7 and ceil?

```
const daysSinceSignup = moment().diff(timestamp, "days");
return Math.ceil(daysSinceSignup / 7);
```

Did you miss out on coffee this morning? ;-)

---

Note: The function above will tell you "the number of the week since `timestamp`" which is what I understand from your text, but your code sample does not reflect it.

To get the same result of your code sample, you'll need to `.floor()` and add 1 instead of `.ceil()`:

```
const daysSinceSignup = moment().diff(timestamp, "days");
return Math.floor(daysSinceSignup / 7) + 1;
```

Comment: You need `Math.floor` as OP wants `<=6` equals zero.

Comment: He wants it to equal 1 though, but I think `+1` is needed, since he wants 7 to equal 2, even though it's semantically wrong with the name of the function.

Comment: With this, `0` returns `0` instead of `1` and `6.5 + 7 * n` for any integer `n` returns `n` instead of `n + 1`. Not sure if that's important or not.

Comment: Lastly, this doesn't account for `if` and `else`, just all the `else if` statements.

Comment: I noticed a problem in the answer. If the startDate=today, it gives me 0th week?

Answer (score 2):

As @Michel said, divide by 7 and floor + 1

```
calculateUsersCurrentWorkoutWeek: function(timestamp) {
    let daysSinceSignup = moment().diff(timestamp, "days");
    return Math.floor(daysSinceSignup / 7) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easy way could also be to create a integer array in ascending order so that the values contain the upper limit of the comparison. Then for each values of `daysSinceSignup` you can find the index and add `1` to it since you require the return values as `1`, `2`, `3`, ... and so on. This will be useful if you do not have uniform interval, like currently the interval is always `7` so the `division` and `ceil` approach could also work but if the interval is not uniform then this approach could be really useful.

```js
var indexArray = [6,13,20,27,34,41,48,55,62,69,76,83,90,97];
function calculateUsersCurrentWorkoutWeek() {
  let daysSinceSignup = 14;
  var elemIndex = indexArray.findIndex((item)=> item > daysSinceSignup);
  return elemIndex+1;
}
console.log(calculateUsersCurrentWorkoutWeek());
```

Comment: Decent try but I am looking for something cleaner, or magical.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is

```
return Math.ceil((daysSinceStartup + 1) / 7);
```

This will give the same results as your code for any real number between -1 and 62 (because around 62 you forgot to replace the copied ranges). It returns 1 for 6 days, and 2 for 6.01 days, just as the original code.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your datas in array and use array.find:

```js
var datas = [
    { min: -Infinity, max: 6, ret: 1 },
    { min: 6, max: 13, ret: 2 },
    { min: 13, max: 20, ret: 3 },
    { min: 20, max: 27, ret: 4 }
];

function calculateUsersCurrentWorkoutWeek(daysSinceSignup) {
    return datas.find(({min, max}) => 
        daysSinceSignup > min && daysSinceSignup <= max
    ).ret;
}

console.log(calculateUsersCurrentWorkoutWeek(5));
console.log(calculateUsersCurrentWorkoutWeek(7));
console.log(calculateUsersCurrentWorkoutWeek(14));
```